# Import single function from lodash in Angular 2 + webpack project

Tags: angular, webpack, lodash

A very common question.

How do you import a single function from lodash?

I tried [lodash.orderby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.orderby), but I believe that is supposed to be used with commonjs. I also tried [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) without much success. I still get a variety of errors such as `Cannot find module 'lodash-es'` or `Cannot find module 'lodash/orderBy'`.

Another possibility was to use [custom builds](https://lodash.com/custom-builds), but I couldn't figure out how to import a single function correctly.

Running Angular 2 RC-4, typescript 2.1.0-dev, webpack 2 (beta).

Typescript is configured in the following way:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm currently importing the module in the following way:

```
import {orderBy} from 'lodash-es';
```

This is actually working (that is, the app is using orderBy correctly), but the error persists. I believe the issue is that there are no type definition for lodash-es.

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160613154055",
    "typeahead": "registry:dt/typeahead#0.11.1+20160317120654"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "registry:npm/lodash#4.0.0+20160416211519"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

This is an old question, but for future reference, if you're not using `require`, you might need to install the correct typing information. In this particular case, I needed to install and declare the module lodash-es.

Comment: What is content of your `typings.json` file and how you are importing the orderby ?

Comment: Do not import lodash.orderby, require it.

Comment: @tomastrajan I updated my question with more information. I think the typing definitions are not available for lodash-es. I was including the definition for lodash and that's what you can see in typings.json.

Comment: @estus But I'm not using commonjs.

Comment: @RobertSmith Webpack does.

Comment: @estus You can configure that in `tsconfig.json`. I changed it to es6. Furthermore, that doesn't make a difference because the import statements are working, but the typing definition are the main issue.

Comment: What made you think that typings are the issue here? tsconfig.json has nothing to do with this. It configures TS and is applied to `import`s. It is Webpack that bundles `require`s. `lodash.orderby` can be required by `require('lodash.orderby')`. It is a way to go when ES6 and CJS modules are mixed. `lodash-es` is not usable here because it has js files as ES6 modules which cannot be mixed with TS at this moment.

Comment: @estus Because the issues disappear when you declare the module lodash-es. I know webpack uses `require`, but I'm not using that for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Install the function required:

```
npm install --save lodash.countby @types/lodash.countby
```

Then import it using:

```
const countBy = require('lodash.countBy');
```

Comment: This was an old question, but as far as I can remember, I wasn't using `require`. The issue was about declaring the correct typings.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it is still valid. I spent quite some time on it. And since answer is hidden in commets to your question I made it more visible by submitting the answer. Anyways this is the only way I found how to do that.

Comment: It is valid but not for this particular question. I will update the question to describe what worked in this case.